# Javascript - How to protect duplicate call connect?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a call center application, where ten agents in ten different computers logged in, they receive a call at the same time, now who ever clicks first, he gets the job. Problem is if ten agents clicks at the same time at then duplicate actions get triggered.

Following method is clicked by the AGENTS. 
On execute, in the database it change the `result_status=fail` to prevent duplicate call answer. But for some reason when all clicks at the same time still duplicate is happening.

```
function connect(input1,input2) {

  $.post(root + '/agent', {
      action: 'xyz',
      callerid: 10,

  }, function(msg) {
    if (msg.result == 'fail') {
      console.log('ALREADY --- CONNECTED --- BUSY');
      return false;
    }
    else {
      new_connection();
    }

  });    
}
```

PHP:

```
public function agentAction() {
    $this->_response->setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');       
    $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();   

    $this->db = Application_Model_Db::db_load();        

    $sql = "select *from sh_av_users where id='{$_POST['callerid']}' and callstatus='ring' limit 1";  

    $result = $this->db->fetchAll($sql);    
    $json = '';
    if (count($result) > 0) {
      $this->db->update('sh_av_users', 
                        array(
                              'callstatus' => 'busy'), 
                        array('id=?' => $_POST['callerid'] ));
      $json = array(
          'result' =>'ok',
      );      
    }   else {
      $json = array(
          'result' => 'fail',

      );        
    } 

    $this->getResponse()
            ->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
            ->setBody(Zend_Json::encode($json))
            ->sendResponse();

    exit;
  }
```

How to handle it so that it only can be answer by one AGENT not duplicate agents?

Comment: You cannot do what you want to do with a stateless application. You can get close, but it may not be satisfactory. Timing issues can only be handled well in applications where state exists.

Comment: I am unable / mission impossible to resolve it. I have to move away from AJAX and do state with NodeJS, its killing my project. on every call i have duplicate answers. Thank you.